Problem while installing ROS-humble with chocolatey on Windows
I am trying to install ROS on windows following the following Isaac Sim installation guide: https://docs.omniverse.nvidia.com/isaacsim/latest/installation/install_ros.html#isaac-sim-app-install-ros
based on a ROS2 binary installation: https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/SetupRos2.html
When running the commands in Installing ROS 2 Binaries section:
mkdir c:\opt\chocolatey
set ChocolateyInstall=c:\opt\chocolatey
choco source add -n=ros-win -s="https://aka.ms/ros/public" --priority=1
choco upgrade ros-humble-desktop -y --execution-timeout=0 --pre

I keep getting a message asking me to provide credentials for https://aka.ms/ros/public:

code version:
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Upgrading the following packages:
ros-humble-desktop
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
ros-humble-desktop is not installed. Installing...
Invalid credentials specified.
Please provide credentials for: https://aka.ms/ros/public
User name:
Password:

After 3 tries I end up having the following error message:

Detailed version:
No password specified, this will probably error.
Unable to connect to source 'https://aka.ms/ros/public':
 Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://ros-win.pkgs.visualstudio.com/ros-win/_packaging/public/nuget/v2/Packages()?$filter=tolower(Id)%20eq%20'ros-humble-desktop'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Le code d'état de réponse n'indique pas la réussite : 401 (Unauthorized).
ros-humble-desktop not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://aka.ms/ros/public;https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.
Failures
 - ros-humble-desktop - ros-humble-desktop not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://aka.ms/ros/public;https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more

I have tried the install on 2 separate machines, but keep getting the error.

Please paste any console output as code formatted text, and not as screenshots. Images are not text searchable, amongst other things...

I had a similar issue that just now resolved on it's own. So it might have been an ROS issue. Does the problem still persist?

That shouldn't require a password. There might be a misconfiguration on the Microsoft servers. I would suggest reaching out to them.

2024-11-21 13:49:04,119 13952 [ERROR] -  - ros-noetic - ros-noetic not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
Source(s): 'https://aka.ms/ros/public;https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify --pre,
the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
assistance.
still I am also getting the same problem, is there any solution available?

Instructions for installing ROS from Microsoft-hosted Chocolatey resources no longer work. See https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/113427/problems-installing-ros1-melodic-under-win-10/113472#113472
