Problems installing ROS1 Melodic under Win 10
Gee whiz. This is going to be heavily edited. Apparently I can't include detailed links in the errors or in the discussion of what I've done, so I need to
remove most of them.
I'm trying to install ROS1 under Windows 10. I have security restrictions against virtual machines AND I have some EtherCAT hardware.
So this looks like a good solution: ROS Melodic under Win 10 plus SOEM.
Looking at SOEM, and of course finding it a dozen other ways ....
<>>>
... gets me to ....
https://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows
Hit the Melodic tab up top.
This is a new computer, tons of space, fresh install of EVERYTHING!
I've installed VS 2019. I use VS quite a lot. I mean, really a lot. This isn't my first rodeo, as they say. I turned on all the C++ desktop options....
I installed Chocolatey.
I'm following the instructions under section 5.1 ROS last known good build installation ....
I fire up x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019, run as administrator ....
I get errors from the last line of the cut and paste instructions:

choco upgrade ros-melodic-desktop_full -y --execution-timeout=0

Here's the output:
C:\Windows\System32>choco upgrade ros-melodic-desktop_full -y --execution-timeout=0
Chocolatey v2.3.0
Upgrading the following packages:
ros-melodic-desktop_full
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
ros-melodic-desktop_full is not installed. Installing...
Unable to connect to source 'https://aka.ms/ros/public':
Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://ros.org/Packages()?$filter=(tolower(Id)%20eq%20'ros-melodic-desktop_full')%20and%20IsLatestVersion&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
ros-melodic-desktop_full not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
Source(s): 'https://aka.ms/ros/public;https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify --pre,
the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
assistance.
Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
See the log for details (<<>>).
Failures

ros-melodic-desktop_full - ros-melodic-desktop_full not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
Source(s): 'https://aka.ms/ros/public;https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify --pre,
the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
assistance.

C:\Windows\System32>
A lot of that output up above is all bright red. Very pretty, but not what I'm looking for.
I go to:
<<>>
... which says this is likely a cut and paste error. I can believe that. Seems obvious, and I don't see any funky MS translation, but I double check by typing the commands in notepad:
choco upgrade ros-melodic-desktop_full -y --execution-timeout=0
No, not a cut and paste error. No change at all.
Chocolatey logs include these errors:
2024-10-22 09:22:19,417 5840 [INFO ] - [NuGet]   NotFound https://ros.org/$metadata 88ms
2024-10-22 09:22:19,557 5840 [INFO ] - [NuGet]   <<<URL to ROS org root>>>/Packages()?$filter=(tolower(Id) eq 'ros-melodic-desktop_full') and IsLatestVersion&semVerLevel=2.0.0 96ms
2024-10-22 09:22:19,573 5840 [WARN ] - Unable to connect to source 'https://aka.ms/ros/public':
Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://ros.org/Packages()?$filter=(tolower(Id)%20eq%20'ros-melodic-desktop_full')%20and%20IsLatestVersion&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
2024-10-22 09:22:20,042 5840 [ERROR] -  - ros-melodic-desktop_full - ros-melodic-desktop_full not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
Looks like the package as been MOVED somewhere in the Wiki. Where?
OK... so i duckduckgo ROS Melodic package download ....
This takes me immediately to ...
https://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation
That's a new page. Ah ha! So I hit the Tier 1 Supported OS plaform for Windows 10 ...!
And at takes me right back to...
<<>>
... which is where I started up above...?

I think maybe Microsoft stopped supporting Chocolatey ROS installations.

Ah. Looks like melodic is end-of-life. Well that's inconvenient.

When it comes to the officially supported channels, there are up-to-date Windows binary install instructions for ROS 2:
https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html

Go to the releases page: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/releases
Download the latest package for Windows, e.g., ros2-jazzy-*-windows-release-amd64.zip.

It seems like Microsoft hosting and support for Chocolatey installs for both ROS 1 and ROS 2 has ended. See this comment and this comment from Lou Amadio at Microsoft. The latter:

Thank you for your interest in ROS on Windows.
As mentioned in that comment, Microsoft has sunset its distribution endpoint of ROS on Windows and recommends using the Windows distributions provided by Open Robotics

So I think any instructions referencing the Microsoft Chocolatey method are simply obsolete. I am not aware of an official Open Robotics binary install alternative for ROS 1, and I doubt one is planned. Even ROS 1 Noetic is end-of-life in May 2025.
ROS 2 on Windows will be actively supported, and I'd move on to ROS 2 if you can. See the ROS discourse thread here for results of a recent community survey and some future action items for refinements of the installation process:

We will invest some more time into producing Windows native libraries. In particular, we will switch to MSVC 2022 and Windows 11 (hopefully for Kilted). We’ll also switch to using Conda as the preferred solution to install our dependencies (rather than our current hodge-podge of dependency installation).

If you can't move on to ROS 2, you might consider the Robostack project for a Windows binary install:
https://robostack.github.io/noetic.html
https://robostack.github.io/GettingStarted.html
The approach there is to use Miniforge to install all of the required ROS dependencies in a Conda environment, which is just an isolated folder of native binaries and a customized shell environment. Technically there's even a Melodic option if you must, but it's not updated.
