Trouble installing ROS in Windows environment
I am trying to install ROS on a Windows10 environment using this protocole :
http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows
However at the command "choco upgrade git -y)", I am getting the following error :
Failures

git - Unable to resolve dependency: Unable to find a version of 'chocolatey-core.extension' that is compatible with 'git.install 2.47.0.20241025 constraint: chocolatey-core.extension (>= 1.3.3)'.

Do you know how to bypass it ?
Thank you for your help.

I don't know why you can't install Git from Chocolatey but those instructions generally aren't valid anymore. See https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/113427/problems-installing-ros1-melodic-under-win-10/113472#113472
